# IUPAC nomenclature of protonated aminoacids

Tags: nomenclature, amino-acids

[image]

> What is the IUPAC systematic name for the above compound.

So I know that carboxylic acids have highest priority. Now the length of carbon chain is 7. So I think the name should be **7-ammonioheptanoic acid**. Am I correct?

Comment: Since this is a cation, I would suppose there should be "-ium" somewhere. For the neutral molecule, 7‐aminoheptanoic acid is correct IMO.

Comment: @andselisk Ig, OP used *ammonio-* which is used as prefix for $\ce{NH4+}$ more commonly. Name seems correct to me, don't know if it's legitimate name according to IUPAC rules..

Comment: @Zenix My bad, you are correct, IUPAC Blue Book from 2013 indeed allows to denote $\ce{-\overset{+}{N}H3}$ with *ammonio-*.

Comment: ChemDraw dubiously says the name is 6-carboxyhexan-1-aminium ...

Answer (score 5):

Interestingly, Ammonium salts come above acids in the seniority table for functional groups (Reference: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_organic_chemistry#Order_of_precedence_of_groups)). Also, the ion in question has an alkyl group attached to it, which makes the suffix *aminium* rather than the commonly used *ammonium*. (Reference: [Gold Book](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/A00277), [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium#Organic_ammonium_ions))  This means that the correct name of the compound is **6-carboxyhexan-1-aminium**. This was also checked with ChemDraw online, as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: "suffix" or "prefix" (or am I turned around somehow)?

Comment: Suffix=after root word, Prefix=before root word. So in this name, the prefix is carboxy and suffix is aminium